# How to access 'Final Balance

Tags: php

After Json Decode how do I access the 'final_balance' value ?

```
    Array
        (
            [19BCZwWvYVh5yRLgdT6Yicnou8iYy7TUaS] => Array
                (
                    [final_balance] => 154014
                    [n_tx] => 1
                    [total_received] => 154014
                )
        )
```

Ive tried this

```
$json1a = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1a), true);

$balance1 = $json1a[0]['final_balance'];

echo $balance1;
```

but no go, thanks

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392906/2469308

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the key before-hand use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$json1a = array_values($json1a);

echo $json1a[0]['final_balance'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json1a = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1a), true);

$json1a = array_values($json1a);

$balance1 = $json1a[0]['final_balance'];

echo $balance1;
```

Edited, following Lawrence Cherone's answer.

Comment: is that the only way? That sting value (19BCZwWvYVh5yRLgdT6Yicnou8iYy7TUaS) will be different most of the time

Comment: @DEM use key($json1a)

Comment: Lawrence Cherone's answer will work, it creates a numeric index, so it will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the key, you can fetch the first key from the array:

```
$json1a = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1a), true);

$balance1 = $json1a[key($json1a)]['final_balance'];

echo $balance1;
```